# How can I add a private key to my keychain?

Tags: keychain

I am trying to add `myRepositoryKey` to my Mac keychain utility so . I exported this item in OpenRSA format from Putty. When I try to use `Import Items`, the file is unselectable. What do I need to do to import into my keychain? Does the file need a specific extension?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You have to create a `.p12` file. In order to do that you need your private key and a certificate for that key. Then run the following on your console:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -clcerts -inkey private.key -in certificate.crt -out MyPKCS12.p12 -name "Your Name"
```

where `private.key` is your existing private RSA key, `certificate.crt` is your existing certificate and `MyPKCS12.p12` is the name of the file to create. This file can then be imported into your keychain.

If you need your key for SSH access (SFTP, SCP or similar), it doesn't have to be in your keychain. Simply copy your private key to `~/.ssh/` and edit/create the `~/.ssh/config` file. There you would put something along these lines:

```
# replace the host, location of the private key and the remoteUserName
# with valid values.
Host remote.domain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private.key
    User remoteUserName
```

Comment: What do you mean by a certificate for the key? Would I have to involve a signing authority?

Comment: Yes, or sign one yourself, although I would not recommend that for anything else than personal use.

Comment: Just an FYI, the command worked for me using a *.pem* rather than a *.crt* for the certificate. I first tried to convert the *.pem* to a *.crt*, which failed, then just tried the *.pem* in the command you've shown directly and that actually worked!

Comment: it did create p12 file in my case but with this error "unable to load certificates" what does that mean?

Comment: You might have saved my job. I was breaking my head over this for hours.

Answer (score 35):

Well I don't get that "need a certificate for the key" either...

I just do `ssh-add -K /path/to/private/key`.

However, make sure you're using Mac's built-in `ssh-add` and not Macports' one (if you ever needed to upgrade OpenSSH).

So, just do `/usr/bin/ssh-add -K /path/to/private/key`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Correct: the built-in SSH must add the key, then both the built-in SSH and the MacPorts SSH can use it.

Comment: Note that you might encounter that "Permission %%%% for ... are too open. [...] This private key will be ignored." Take a look [on this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9270753/2442804) to fix that issue.

Comment: Nice. Pity there is no Keychain GUI support to do this, seems trivial.

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to import a .p12 using Keychain's GUI just to be silently ignored under Lion. So just for completeness, I'd like to this post in Stephan's Blog

http://www.arlt.eu/blog/2009/12/01/importing-iphone-keys-p12-and-pem-into-snow-leopards-keychain/

In short, this should do the trick every time:

```
security import priv_key.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
security import pub_key.pem -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering all in PEM format, private key file is server-key.key and certificate file is server-cert.pem.

```
# create .p12 formatted file with key and certificate using openssl. 
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server-cert.pem -inkey server-key.key -passout pass:password -out certificate.p12 -name "SCProxy"

# should use -T appPath. -A means this key is accessible for all apps. 
sudo security import certificate.p12 -A -P password -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain" server-cert.pem
```

Comment: `-T` no longer works in Sierra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868578/security-codesign-in-sierra-keychain-ignores-access-control-settings-and-ui-p